# Photo Competition 2021-12-20: Shot with Film

Tags: film, photo-competition

### Theme: Shot with Film

Kodak Portra, Tri-X, Ilford Delta, Fujicolor Pro, ... any film you want, digitized however is convenient — but shot on film, with minimal digital post-production.

Entries should be photographs taken recently, well into the digital era, rather than older works. There's no way to enforce this, of course, but please follow it in the spirit of the theme.

This theme was suggested by [mattdm](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](//photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128032/photo-competition-2021-12-20-shot-with-film?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on January 3, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Flower Stem, Studio**
[image: Flower Stem]

Flower Stem, studio strobe/softbox
Shen-Hao 4x5, Nikkor 120mm Macro 1/125 f/16, Tri-X Pan, ISO 320
Epson 4870 scanner

Answer (score 7):

**Birthday Morning**
[image: Queens Park, London]

I normally don't get up early, but thought I would try my luck on my birthday. Queen's Park, London (2021)

Kodak Ultramax 400, Pentax P30, 50mm f/1.7

Answer (score 3):

**Red and Silver**
2018, location withheld.

Nikon F3HP, Nikkor 50mm f/1.8, Ilford FP4+. Exposure settings unknown.

This is a triptych of three separate photographs. All three photos were digitally altered identical to previously made silver gelatin prints.

[image]

Comment: Looks very surreal, nice! What object/landscape/thing was photographed?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Thank you! I don't intend to spoil the mystique of the subject, so I leave it up to the beholder to guess.

Comment: Alright, sounds fair :)

Answer (score 3):

**NCAR/Boulder**
[image: NCAR/Boulder]

Meadow near NCAR, Boulder
Shen-Hao 4x5, Nikkor 90mm 1/125 f/16, Ektar 100
Epson 4870 scanner

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Sparkling light**
September 13, 2021. [Kahlenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahlenberg), Vienna, Austria.
Minolta XG-1, Kodak T-Max 400, 1/250s

I got extremely lucky when I stumbled into an engagement of two persons up on the Kahlenberg, in front of a beautiful panoramic view of the city of Vienna, together with a friend of mine. It was a cloud-less night and the sun had already set; thus the weather provided us with the most perfect conditions to capture the firework the bridegroom-to-be had organised.

Scanned by my lab of trust using a Noritsu Koki QS-3233. No digital editing done.

Answer (score 1):

**Diana/Artemis, Goddess of the Hunt**

[image: Diana/Artemis]

Garden, Northwestern University
Shen-Hao 4x5, Nikkor 150mm 1/30 f/8, Delta 100 Pro
Epson 4870 Scanner